# Static assert template parameter check while creating an alias

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits, c++17

Let's say we have the structure where I need to check the types of template parameters (wchar_t is just an example):

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, wchar_t>::value, "Failure");
}
```

Of course following code will not compile:

```
Foo<int> foo;
```

But how can I prevent from compiling:

```
using foo = Foo<int>;
```

?

Comment: Just instantiate foo (the type alias), it is the same. Aslong as you dont instantiate it the compiler does not "produce" the code and the assertion is not checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't compile when you try to actually create `foo`? You change the meaning of `foo` once it's a variable, and once it's a type.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, wchar_t>::value, "Failure");
};

using FooINT = Foo<int>;

int main() {
    FooINT foo; // breaks
    return 0;
}
```

So you basically define a type alias that is useless. Unfortunately creating a specific alias does not result in immediate instantiation of the type.

To elaborate a bit more. `using` just introduces an alias, it does not "produce" the type, so the following is possible:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, wchar_t>::value, "Failure");
};

using FooINT = Foo<int>; // should it break now or not?

template <>
struct Foo<int> {
    int A_OK;
};

int main() {
    FooINT foo; // works now
    return 0;
}
```

So you cannot make `using FooINT = Foo<int>;` not compile by itself. You would need some mechanism to actually instantiate the template.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I wasn't specific enough, because what I wanted to achieve to prevent compiling just using foo = Foo<int>; without previous instantation. But due to what you're saying it's impossible.

Comment: Yeah, I added an example, which kind of shows what would be impossible, or confusing, if your proposal worked. This probably why alias is just an alias, and doesn't do much more, except maybe for performance reasons.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to produce an error on line `using FooINT = Foo<int>;` you can use instead a default template parameter:

```
template <
    typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, wchar_t>::value>
>
struct Foo { };
```